# How to get the data from an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to get the user input for the EditText and put it in a URL through String Concatenation but when the Button is clicked to get the data from URL, the app crashes. Also when i put value in concatenation manually, the data is fetched from the URL all fine

Comment: Please can you add some more details.

Comment: Can you please show the code snippet for more provide understanding?

Comment: can you share crash here ?